# mpi communicator for each element of an array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, mpi, function-pointers

I'm new to MPI and not sure if this is the right approach. Or if I am supposed to use MPI in this manner but my problem is the following:

I have an array of pointers to user defined structures. Depending on what's happening in each process, an element of the array may either be NULL or a pointer to the instance of the user defined structure. I now need the elements of the array to communicate with each other over MPI. This is problematic, since some of them do not exist.

I should elaborate: The structure has a function pointer to the function in which the communication needs to happen. If the element exists, the function gets called. If not, not.

My Idea: create a dedicated MPI communicator for each element of the array that includes all the processors on which the element is NOT NULL. Then refer to this communicator during communication for the respective element.

Can I create an "array" of MPI communicators, one for each element of the array? And then reference MPI_COMM_ARRAY[i] for each element?
Or am I just completely on a dead end and shouldn't use NULL as array entries at all?
What is the "clean" way of coding this?

This is a simplification of what I have right now. It works if by chance the cells exist across all processes. It fails if they don't.
Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>


void * createcell();
void Cell_givenumberofvertices(void * _self, int * NbOfVertices);
void Cell_givenumberofvertices_parallel(void * _self, int * NbOfVertices);
void Cell_addvertex(void * _self);
void addvertex(void * _self);
void getnumberofvertices(void * _self, int * NbOfVertices);


struct Cell{
  unsigned NbOfVertices;
  void (* givenumberofvertices)(void * _self, int * NbOfVertices);
  void (* addvertex)(void * _self);
};

void * createcell(){
  struct Cell * self = calloc(1, sizeof(struct Cell));
  int world_size;

  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);

  self->NbOfVertices = 0;
  self->addvertex = Cell_addvertex;

  if(world_size==0) self->givenumberofvertices = Cell_givenumberofvertices;
  else self->givenumberofvertices = Cell_givenumberofvertices_parallel;

  return self;
}

void Cell_givenumberofvertices(void * _self, int * NbOfVertices){
   struct Cell * self = _self;
   * NbOfVertices = self->NbOfVertices;
   return;
}

void Cell_givenumberofvertices_parallel(void * _self, int * NbOfVertices){
  struct Cell * self = _self;
  int world_size, world_rank;
  int i;
  int * NbVertxOnProcess;
  int totalnumberofvertices=0;

  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_rank);
  NbVertxOnProcess = (int *) malloc(world_size*sizeof(int));

  MPI_Gather(&(self->NbOfVertices),1,MPI_UNSIGNED,NbVertxOnProcess,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  for(i=0;i<world_size;i++) totalnumberofvertices+=NbVertxOnProcess[i];

   * NbOfVertices = totalnumberofvertices;
   return;
}

void Cell_addvertex(void * _self){
  struct Cell * self = _self;
  self->NbOfVertices ++;
  return;
}

 void addvertex(void * _self){
   struct Cell * self = _self;
   self->addvertex(self);
 }

 void getnumberofvertices(void * _self, int * NbOfVertices){
  struct Cell * self = _self;
  self->givenumberofvertices(self, NbOfVertices);
 }  



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  void ** cells;
  int i,j;
  const int numberofcells = 100;
  const int numberofvertices = 100;
  const float domainlength = 115.4;
  float grid[numberofcells];
  float vertexcoordinates[numberofvertices];
  int world_rank;

  MPI_Init(NULL,NULL);

  /* create array of Cell pointers */
  cells = (void **) calloc(numberofcells,sizeof(void *));

  /* create grid */
  for(i=0;i<numberofcells;i++){
    grid[i]=domainlength/numberofcells*(i+1);
  }
  /* generate random vertex coordinates */
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&world_rank);
  srand((unsigned int) world_rank);
  for(i=0;i<numberofvertices;i++){
    vertexcoordinates[i]=((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX)) * domainlength;
  }
  /* find the cell the vertex is in */
  for(i=0;i<numberofvertices;i++){
    for(j=0;j<numberofcells;j++){
      float lb, ub;
      if(j==0) lb=0.0;
      else lb=grid[j-1];
      ub = grid[j];
      if(lb<vertexcoordinates[i]&&vertexcoordinates[i]<ub){
         if(!cells[j]){
          cells[j]=createcell();
         }
        addvertex(cells[j]);
      }
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<numberofcells;i++){
     if(cells[i]){
      int NbVertxInCell;
      getnumberofvertices(cells[i], &NbVertxInCell);
      printf("%i vertices in cell number %i \n",NbVertxInCell,i);
    }
  }
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show some code, your explanation is very hard to follow. For example, "array of user defined structures" seens to be an array  to user defined structures.

Comment: Fair enough, I hope it is clearer now. The problem lies within the function *Cell_givenumberofvertices_parallel()*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not get the full picture of what you are trying to achieve nor the rationale for such a design.

Anyway, here are some thoughts.

First, be aware that when invoking a collective operation, all tasks from the communicator should invoke it, otherwise some tasks may hang.

Second, in `Cell_givenumberofvertices_parallel()`, you can replace `MPI_Gather()` with `MPI_Reduce()`. And since the main loop print on all the ranks, i believe you really want `MPI_Allreduce()`

I also suspect you want to add a `MPI_Comm * comm` field to `struct Cell`,
otherwise not all ranks invoke the collective on `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and that will hang.

Third, i do not see the need for a pointer function.

If a cell is only on one task, then the comm should be `MPI_COMM_SELF`, and you can use `MPI_Allreduce()` so there is no need for two subroutines.

Last but not least, i do not see how the function can return different values over time, so the total number of vertices can be computed at initialization, and stored as new field.

for example, that could be

```
struct Cell{
  unsigned localNbOfVertices;
  unsigned totalNbOfVertices;
  MPI_Comm comm;
};
```

and in your main loop, you can

```
  for(i=0;i<numberofcells;i++){
     unsigned local=0, total;
     MPI_Comm comm;
     if(cells[i]) local=cells[i]->localNbOfVertices;
     MPI_Allreduce(&local, &total, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, MPI_SUM, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
     if(cells[i] cells[i]->totalNbOfVertices = total;
     printf("%i vertices in cell number %i \n",total,i);
     if(cells[i]) MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 0, world_rank, &cells[i]->comm); else MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_UNDEFINED, world_rank, &comm);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, I might have oversimplified the code in my quest to produce a small example. I the actual application, the vertex positions change over time. Also the function *get/givenumberovertices()* is just a simplified representation. In the real application, the employed function depends on the number of vertices and their location. Adding an MPI_Comm * comm to struct Cell sounds like what I'm looking for. But I struggle to understand where and how to create that new communicator. If I do it in *createCell()*, I don't know on which other processors the cell exists.

Comment: i updated my answer with the communicator creation. the cell communicator should be created once all your cell have been initialized.